# Android development: Best way to keep development files

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been playing around with Android development in Eclipse. I'm a regular .NET developer. In Visual Studio project folder I can always create a new folder to keep my backup files / development data / unfinished graphics / photoshop files / etc. This folder does not get compiled with the project because it is not been added to the project. But the most convenient thing for me is that I get to keep the project development files and source code within the same directory structure.

What is the best practice for Eclipse. How do people keep their photoshop and other development files along with the project files so that it doesn't gets compiled into the apk file; and they're all located in the same project directory.

F.A.

Comment: i honestly tried Eclipse more than 1-2-3 times, i have tried to work with Eclipse like a lot of times, everytime i just give up because is extremely slow, resource hungry, buggy, and the workbench and the workspace are 2 special things that are poorly design and perform really bad as long as you keep going adding projects and new files to your space. in my opinion the best setup is always compiler + terminal + doxygen ( or equivalent ) + text editor + git ; and you can do things with highly reliable tools and really fast.

Comment: I agree. Eclipse isn't a "productive" tool at all. Very poorly designed whereas it does have lots of potential. I'm forced to use it cuz of the "intellisense" feature. Once I get familiar to the coding language and syntax I'll move to text editor, just like I've done with ASP, CSS and related web development langs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a folder in you project and put your files there.It won't get compiled into the apk file except you place the folder into one of the Android default folders like, `src, gen, res, assets ...`

Comment: Works. Thanks. Feels Eclipse needs a big user-friendliness overhaul !!